# How does HBase mapReduce TableOutputFormat use Flush and WAL

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

So while writing to HBase from a MapReduce job which is using TableOutputFormat how often does it write to HBase. I dont imagine it doing a put command for every row.

How do we control AutoFlush and Write Ahead Log (WAL) while using in MapReduce?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TableOutputFormat disables AutoFlush and uses the write buffer specified at hbase.client.write.buffer (defaults to 2MB), once the buffer is full its automatically flushed to HBase. You can change it by adding the property to your job configuration: 
`config.set("hbase.client.write.buffer", 16777216); // 16MB Buffer`

WAL is enabled by default, it can be disabled per put but it's generally discouraged:
`myPut.setWriteToWal(false);`

Answer (score 0):

It does in fact see [the code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/org.apache.hbase/hbase-server/0.98.6-cdh5.3.0/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/mapreduce/TableOutputFormat.java#TableOutputFormat). If you want to bypass the WAL write using HFileOutputFormat [see example on gitub](https://github.com/jrkinley/hbase-bulk-import-example)